# Equivalent to cut command in batch scripts

Tags: batch-file

Is there any utility in windows which carries out same operations done but cut command in unix.

I have input lets say A|B|C|D. Since "|" is the delimiter therefore I need to fetch all values separated by "|".

Kindly advise.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try: `set "input=A|B|C|D"` & `for %%a in ("%input:|=" "%") do echo Value: %%~a`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this in a .cmd file you can probably find some examples by typing `for /?` into your command prompt.  Otherwise if powershell is an option then it's as easy as using `String.Split()`.

Comment: You mean `$string.split('|')`